# Creating O-D cost matrix using ArcGIS Pro with routes from network data and not just straight lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, origin-destination

I want to create a O-D cost matrix which will relate the origins and destinations by a transportation network layer and will not just connect by a straight line.

Can you give me any insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of the ArcGIS Pro Help uncovered the [OD cost matrix analysis layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/od-cost-matrix-analysis-layer.htm) page:

> An OD cost matrix analysis layer finds and measures the least-cost
> paths along the network from multiple origins to multiple
> destinations.

Comment: Thank you! It answers a lot of questions